# Flash Uploadify is not keeping the session/authorization when calling my MVC controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, flash, uploadify

Using Uploadify in Firefox doesn't work while using it in Chrome does. I just kept getting 302 errors from Uploadify. After much head scratching I figured out that this is because Flash does not keep any session information in its requests (wtf?). I saw some solutions involving grabbing the session id from the cookie and passing that along in uploadify so that it can be 'rebuilt'.

However, session ids and auth ids are stored as httponly cookies which means I can't access them with javascript (as far as I know) and my $.uploadify calls are all in strictly .js files. All the solutions showed grabbing these IDs with C# calls using Razor or the original rendering engine which I can't do.

Is there any way around this or am I going to have to pass these IDs from the calling view all the way through multiple javascript calls to reach the uploadify part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I eventually got around it in a way which I don't like much, but it will have to do. Since my $.uploadify calls were in javascript files, I couldn't access the cookies that I needed (they are HTTPONLY cookies). So I just made a trivial server call and grabbed the cookies out of the response and passed them along via the formData.

Answer (score 0):

Could [**this**](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/)***** help?

> In Uploadify, the Flash file is what communicates with the backend script.  Because of a bug in Flash, the session cookie is not picked up by the Flash file.  To circumvent this, you will need to pass the session data via the formData option.  To do this in PHP, use the following code when initializing Uploadify on the front-end page:

Client:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    // Your normal options here
    formData : { '<?php echo session_name();?>' : '<?php echo session_id();?>' }
});
```

Server:

```
$session_name = session_name();

if (!isset($_POST[$session_name])) {
    exit;
} else {
    session_id($_POST[$session_name]);
    session_start();
}
```

**Sure same can be done with C#.*